# jGraphX - Import XML and get it's vertices and edges

Tags: java, mxgraph, jgraphx, jgraph

I am trying to import an `xml` file into a graph object and then iterate through its children (vertices && edges). I am trying the following but does not work for me

```
            String xml = "<root><mxCell> ...... ";
            mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
            Document document = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
            mxCodec codec = new mxCodec(document);
            codec.decode(document.getDocumentElement(), graph.getModel());
            Object[] cells = graph.getChildCells(graph.getDefaultParent()); 
            //get all cells 
            for (Object c : cells) {
                mxCell cell = (mxCell) c; 
                if (cell.isVertex()) { 
                   // if is vertex do some things
                }
            }
```

But the `graph.getChildCells(graph.getDefaultParent())` does not return me any cells. Any idea?

=== EDIT ===

In the [mxgraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript) Javascript library I am converting the same xml into a `graph` object and iterating through it's children (vertices && edges) this way,

```
let doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
let codec = new mxCodec(doc);
codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
let elt = doc.documentElement.firstChild;
while (elt != null)
{ 
    let cell = codec.decode(elt)
    if(cell != undefined){
       if(cell.vertex){
         //is vertex
       }
       else{
         //is edge
       }
       graph.addCell(cell);
    }
    elt = elt.nextSibling;
}
```

which works perfectly, I am trying to implement the same way in the `Java library` the following way:

```
 while (elt != null){
   mxCell mxCell = (mxCell) codec.decode(elt, graph.getModel());
   elt = elt.getNextSibling();           
 }
```

but casting the Object that `codec.decode` produces to an `mxCell` object fails